# FLUTTER: How to know if user has quit quit app?

Tags: flutter, widget

I want to know when a user shutdown my app and I want to call a function before closing it. I heard about widget binding observer but I don't know if it is the right choice. Do you have documentation or code example about this functionnality ?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this repository and detect when the application is destroyed.**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_lifecycle_state

```
class TestRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestRouteState();
}

class _TestRouteState extends StateWithLifecycle<TestRoute> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // You need to set the tag id before the super. InitState () method
    tagInStateWithLifecycle = "_TestRouteState";
    super.initState();
  });

  @override
  void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // todo 
  }

  @override
  void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // todo
  }

  @override
  void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // todo
  }

  @override
  void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // todo
  }
}
```